# icon font not working when generated dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, font-awesome

I am using an ASP.NET WebForms project on .Net Framework 3.5

The following works if I hard-code this in the markup:

```
<span id="staticImg" class="font-css">&#xe901</span>
```

However, when I try to generate the preceding in my generic handler nothing appears. Several whitespace characters appears though.

```
context.Response.Write("<span class='font-css'>" + "&#xe901" + "</span>");
```

The generic handler is being called in the client like this:

```
<iframe src="test.ashx?id=x"></iframe>
```

I adding FontAwesome to tags below for this post, however, there is an abstraction layer generic handler is not talking directly to FontAwesome.

Comment: Which framework do you use? More detailed plz

Comment: .Net Framework 3.5. Unfortunately this is the only detail I have. This is all I have in my generic handler. And this is a web form for client page.

Comment: Again more Details, mvc, webforms...

Comment: On which event do you use this? I can remember, that those kinds of markup stuff is gonna be set earliest in onprerender event

Comment: Ok, I did forget to mention one other detail (and I humbly appologize) and this might be my problem, I don't know. But, I am having to use an <iframe src="test.ashx?id=x"></iframe>. But that's it, that's the whole picture.

Comment: Also updated the OP.

Comment: So plz post the full code